# Python: functools, wrapper decorator for methods: make ipython return proper definition when using '?'

Tags: python, functools

I'm using functools to make a decorator, that allows me to 
log the details of a method call.

I got a lot of help here to write it...it's not my own and I'm still
learning how it even works...

I work out of ipython a lot and when I use:

```
import Tools
imagetools = Tools.Tools()
imagetools.save_new_image ?

Type:       instancemethod
String Form:<bound method ImageTools.save_new_image of <ImageTools.ImageTools object      at    0x305d1d0>>
File:       /fs/corpus6/dpc/workspace/python/Modules/MiscTools.py
Definition: imagetools.save_new_image(self, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:  <no docstring>
```

This is my problem line...besides that I didn't write doc string yet... :|

```
Definition: imagetools.save_new_image(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

I'd it to be:

```
save_new_image_clone(self, data, header, outfile,  coordmap)
```

Wrapper:

```
import functools

def log_method(func):

@functools.wraps(func)
def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.__doc__ = func.__doc__
    # allows me to put the wrapper in helper methods that are sometimes major steps
    if check_for_True_in_last_arg(*args):
        log.debug('''Last arg is "True" which could indicate the caller 
intends the log to work on this method. For that behaviour, use the keyword arg:  log_this=True''')

    if 'log_this' in kwargs and kwargs['log_this'] is not False: 
        args_name = inspect.getargspec(func)[0][1:] #drop the 'self' arg
        args_dict = dict(list(itertools_izip(args_name, args)) + list(kwargs.iteritems()))
        method_name = wrapper.__name__
        args_dict_string = '\nMETHOD: ' + method_name + '\n'

        for k,v in args_dict.iteritems():
            if type(v) is not np.ndarray:
                args_dict_string += "%s: %s\n" %(k,v)

            elif type(v) is np.ndarray:
                args_dict_string += "NUMPY ARRAY:%s \nSHAPE:%s\n" %(k, str(v.shape))

        args_dict_string += '\n'
        log.info(args_dict_string)

    return func(self, *args, **kwargs) 

return wrapper
```

UPDATE:
From within ipython I did this to see what's happening, but it didn't help me yet..

```
help??
Type:       _Helper
String Form:Type help() for interactive help, or help(object) for help about object.
File:       /usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py
Definition: help(self, *args, **kwds)
Source:

class _Helper(object):
"""Define the builtin 'help'.
This is a wrapper around pydoc.help (with a twist).

"""

def __repr__(self):
    return "Type help() for interactive help, " \
           "or help(object) for help about object."
def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
    import pydoc
    return pydoc.help(*args, **kwds)

Call def:   help(self, *args, **kwds)
```

Comment: In Python 3, there's such a thing called a "signature object." A wrapper function can duplicate (or point to) the wrapped function's signature. In fact, `functools.wraps` even sets this up properly. The problem is, Python`s `help()` does not follow this pointer—or use the signature object in any way, for that matter. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do -- make a decorator whose call signature is identical to the function being decorated -- is not a simple thing to do from scratch. There is a third-party module, called [decorator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator), which can do this however:

```
import decorator

@decorator.decorator
def log_method(func, *args, **kwargs):
    # allows me to put the wrapper in helper methods that are sometimes major steps
    if check_for_True_in_last_arg(*args):
        log.debug('''Last arg is "True" which could indicate the caller 
intends the log to work on this method. For that behaviour, use the keyword arg:  log_this=True''')

    if 'log_this' in kwargs and kwargs['log_this'] is not False: 
        args_name = inspect.getargspec(func)[0][1:] #drop the 'self' arg
        args_dict = dict(list(itertools_izip(args_name, args)) + list(kwargs.iteritems()))
        method_name = wrapper.__name__
        args_dict_string = '\nMETHOD: ' + method_name + '\n'

        for k,v in args_dict.iteritems():
            if type(v) is not np.ndarray:
                args_dict_string += "%s: %s\n" %(k,v)

            elif type(v) is np.ndarray:
                args_dict_string += "NUMPY ARRAY:%s \nSHAPE:%s\n" %(k, str(v.shape))

        args_dict_string += '\n'
        log.info(args_dict_string)

    return func(self, *args, **kwargs) 

class Tools(object):
    @log_method
    def save_new_image(self, data, header, outfile, coordmap):
        """
        Jazz the snaz output baz
        """
```

Then from IPython:

```
In [14]: imagetools = Tools()

In [15]: imagetools.save_new_image?
Type:       instancemethod
String Form:<bound method Tools.save_new_image of <__main__.Tools object at 0xae1e20c>>
File:       /tmp/python-2973tNk.py
Definition: imagetools.save_new_image(self, data, header, outfile, coordmap)
Docstring:  Jazz the snaz output baz
```

---

If you want to see the Python code which achieves this, see [the decorator.FunctionMaker class](http://code.google.com/p/micheles/source/browse/decorator/src/decorator.py#63). It uses `inspect` to figure out the signature of the original function, then uses string formating to write a `def-statement` defining the decorated function. Then it calls `exec code in evaldict` to execute the string.

Comment: Super awesome answer...it worked with a minor edit, and I've got weekend reading...cheers